# Run a scheduled task wether the user is logged or not

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I want regular users to be able to install USB devices that are on a certain list. I created a script that is launched with administrator privileges by a schedule task when the usb device is plugged. The script verifies that the device is on the list and then installs it using devcon. 
In the schedule task properties, I chose "run this script wether the user is logged on or not " but it seems that it prevents devcon from running properly. However, when I choose "Run only when user is logged on", everything works properly, does somebody have an explanation for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this too with another program (SpeedFan). It seems that when "run this script whether the user is logged on or not" is checked, the "full administrative access token" (elevation) is not granted, even though it runs with High Integrity level. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about UAC to fully explain this phenomenon.